# in search of: official standards organization tag

Tags: discussion, tags

[standard](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/standard) is general, and apt to be misused. Something related to **standards organizations** would be helpful, though. Examples: IEEE, ISO.

What could cover them all? Do you think this would be useful?

Example: [standards-organization](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/standards-organization).

Example of use: [Standard nomenclature for component types](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/10327/2118)

Comment: "Regulatory," "Approved", and "Official" are alternatives I looked at when trying to tag that question.

Comment: ..and one of the answers to the linked question included "canonical"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it even make sense to group multiple organizations into one tag?  I'd rather tag IEEE-related questions [ieee](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ieee), SAE: [sae](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sae), and so on.

If you're looking for standards in general, then I'd just go with just [standards](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/standards).

Comment: What if you don't know them? The linked question is looking for any of them.

Comment: @tyb: If you're looking for standards in general, then I'd just go with what you have shortened to just `[standards]`